# Sinon Spy to check function has been called

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, sinon

I am trying to use `sinon.spy()` to check that a function has been called. The function is called `getMarketLabel` and it returns `marketLabel` and accepts it into the function. I need to check that `getMarketLabel` has been called. I actually call `getMarketLabel` in one place, like so:
`{getMarketLabel(sel.get('market'))}`
The code I have so far is:

```
describe('Check if it has been called', () => {
  let spy;
  beforeEach(() => {
    spy = sinon.spy(getMarketLabel, 'marketLabel');
  })
  it('should have been called', () => {
    expect(spy).to.be.calledWith('marketLabel');
  });
});
```

This is the error I receive:
`TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property marketLabel as function`

Answer (score 2):

Sinon can't spy on functions that aren't a property of some object, because Sinon has to be able to replace the original function `getMarketLabel` by a spied-on version of that function.

A working example:

```
let obj = {
  getMarketLabel(label) {
    ...
  }
}
sinon.spy(obj, 'getMarketLabel');

// This would call the spy:
obj.getMarketLabel(...);
```

This syntax (which is close to what you're using) also exists:

```
let spy = sinon.spy(getMarketLabel);
```

However, this only triggers the spy code when explicitly calling `spy()`; when you call `getMarketLabel()` directly, the spy code isn't called at all.

Also, this won't work either:

```
let getMarketLabel = (...) => { ... }
let obj            = { getMarketLabel }
sinon.spy(obj, 'getMarketLabel');

getMarketLabel(...);
```

Because you're still calling `getMarketLabel` directly.

Comment: @DaveDavidson `sinon.spy(getMarketLabel, 'marketLabel')` is invalid: `getMarketLabel` isn't an object, and `marketLabel` isn't a function.

Answer (score 0):

> This is the error I receive: `TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined
>   property marketLabel as function`

You need to require the helper.js into your test file, then replace the relevant method on the required module and finally call the method replaced with the spy:

```
var myModule = require('helpers'); // make sure to specify the right path to the file

describe('HistorySelection component', () => {
  let spy;
  beforeEach(() => {
    spy = sinon.stub(myModule, 'getMarketLabel'); // replaces method on myModule with spy
  })
  it('blah', () => {
    myModule.getMarketLabel('input');
    expect(spy).to.be.calledWith('input');
  });
});
```

You cannot test whether the spy is called with `helpers.sel('marketLabel')` as this function will be executed before the test is conducted. You will therefore by writing:

`expect(spy).to.be.calledWith(helpers.sel('marketLabel'));`

be testing that that the spy is called with whatever value returned by `helpers.sel('marketLabel')` (which is `undefined` by default).

---

The content of helper.js should be:

```
module.exports = {
  getMarketLabel: function (marketLabel) {
    return marketLabel
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm unsure what should be in the helper file though. Currently this is what I have: https://jsfiddle.net/8q1tLhs7/

And I still receive the same error.

Comment: @DaveDavidson:  See updated answer. Unsure why you do a `return {getMarketLabel}` that is invalid syntax. I changed it to `return marketLabel`.

Comment: This does not work for me. I still get the same error.

Comment: @DaveDavidson: See updated answer. You are trying to stub the method. So you need to use sinon.stub().

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: That is not possible if you have typed everything in correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128618/discussion-between-davedavidson-and-rabbitco).

Comment: @rabbitco `{ getMarketLabel }` is valid ES6 syntax, it's short for `{ getMarketLabel : getMarketLabel }`

Comment: @robertklep: Ahh - thanks! Was not aware of that one yet.